# ROS Fuerte, Pandaboard & Ubuntu 12.04 - no go

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, pandaboard, ubuntu-precise, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get Ros Fuerte working on my Pandaboard over the weekend to no avail, I've just been hitting roadblock after roadblock.

I'll detail the errors I've come across so far, the work-arounds I used and then the final error I can't get around. I'm using a non-ES Pandaboard with a fresh [Ubuntu 12.04 OMAP4 desktop image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap4.img.gz) and the [Fuerte source installation instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source). The proprietary SGX drivers were not installed.

I attempted to install all dependancies, ROS-Full and Desktop-Full install.
There were no proxies present on my network.

**Error 1**: *ros-fuerte-swig-wx* doesn't seem to exist on armel or armhf, causes graphical dependencies to fail at step 1.4. Worked around using plain *swig* instead, though I'm not sure if that has had any negative impact later on.

**Error 2**: *turtle.cpp* fails to compile properly at step 1.5.1, worked around using patched turtle.cpp from the [Raspberry Pi answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/34501/how-to-setting-up-ros-on-raspberrypi/)

**Error 3**: The following layer two packages fail at step 1.7, output from *rosdep install -arvy*

```
 ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y libtbb-dev] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-cg-toolkit] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-ros] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y yaml-cpp] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-pcl] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-opencv2] failed
 apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-fuerte-swig-wx] failed
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [libtbb-dev]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [nvidia-cg-toolkit]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-fuerte-ros]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [yaml-cpp]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-fuerte-pcl]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-fuerte-opencv2]
 apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-fuerte-swig-wx]
```

Some of these are expected, have to rosmake with the -r flag to continue but I think the damage has been done at this point.

**Error 4**: roscore fails to start after the environment is setup. Errors out with the following even when running as root.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/rosversion", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: rospkg==1.0.2 Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

rosversion also has a similar error, but the basic ros filesystem tools (roscd, roscpp, which roscore) seem to work.

At this point I couldn't be bothered looking any further, wiped the SD card, put on Ubuntu 11.10 and installed ROS electric following [these](http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) steps and it worked straight away. Has anyone actually got Fuerte running on a Pandaboard under 12.04 or can provide some insight into these errors? Otherwise is it possible for electric to run under 12.04?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35602/ros-fuerte,-pandaboard--&-ubuntu-12.04---no-go/) by [Bertrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/2522/bertrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Electric is not supported on Ubuntu 12.04. While many packages can be made to work, others will have problems resolving their `rosdep` dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2